# Can you modify the value of a Tensor in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

Can you modify the value of a specific tensor?

For example:

```
x = tf.zeros((2, 2))
x[0, 0] = 1 # pseudo-code
print(x) # <Tensor ... numpy=[[1, 0], [0, 0]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can but you need to set the tensor to be a Variable and not a constant.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((2,2))
x_var = tf.Variable(x)
x[0,0]=1
tf.assign(x_var ,x)
```